# What is "chicken powder"?

Tags: chicken

What is "chicken powder"?

Is off-the-shelf chicken powder considered processed food?

If so, is it possible to make chicken powder at home?

Comment: What do you call "chicken powder"? Bouillon powder, actual dried chicken meat ground into powder, or something else?

Comment: @rumtscho, https://youtu.be/voJJkRAx-0o

Comment: The clickbait recipe doesn't actually say what it is, & asking people to watch 4 minutes of youtube to try spot whether it's any more informative is of no practical use to this site. Find some 'chicken powder' & look at the ingredients list. If it's less than 99% actual dried chicken… it's 'processed'.

Comment: @Tetsujin, *& asking people to watch 4 minutes of youtube to try spot whether it's any more informative is of no practical use to this site.* --- did you notice that the entire recipe in given down under the video?

Comment: @user366312 The recipe which just says "chicken powder"? That doesn't give any further insight as to what it might actually be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "chicken powder", there are two different varieties that come to mind.  One would be the type you can find in Asian supermarkets (typically TTL Chicken Powder or TTL Mushroom Chicken Powder), which appear to be granulated and is similar in functional effect to MSG/I+G/other umami flavor enhancers.  The other that comes to mind would be more accurately called "powdered chicken broth"; these may not be as easily found in the end-consumer market, but more typically for institutional/hospitality/B2B supply chains.

Unfortunately, I cannot find one for the former at the moment, but I do have a product [specification sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8vZAOowFjAVTXBBYlVaNEp3TG8/view?usp=sharing) for the latter, specifically for an IDF product.

Answer (score 4):

Chicken powder is dehydrated chicken bouillon. It is a processed food: if it were not, it would still be a chicken, not powder.

Chicken powder is not something you can make at home; and even if you could, it would still be a processed food. If you have homemade chicken stock (also a processed food) and the recipe calls for water, you can substitute chicken stock  for chicken powder and reduce the water by that amount.

(Water is also a processed food.)

Comment: "Water is also a processed food" I would say there is debate about both the "[processed](https://educhange.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/NOVA-Classification-Reference-Sheet.pdf)" and the "food".

Comment: @User65535 Yes, exactly.